# MIB2 SNMP OID to get physical CPU socket count?

Tags: central-processing-unit, snmp, oid

I am trying to set up a monitoring system and I'm noticing that MIB-2 seems to only report the virtual CPU count (all cores+hyperthreading). I need to get the physical socket CPU count. Is there any snmp agent that can provide an OID for that?

EDIT: Oops, forgot to mention, this is a RHEL 5.5 server.